# Flexbox: Fill clicked row and wrap elements below/above to fill space

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to set up a responsive grid so that when you click on a grid-item, it fills the horizontal space of its row and pushes the other items either above it or below it. To fill the remaining empty space.

Here's my current code which does fill the row but leaves empty space.

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/1L8sg46d/6/)

```js
$(".box").click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("enlarge");
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.enlarge {
  flex-basis: 100% !important;
}

.boxes {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.boxes .box {
  flex-basis: calc((100% / 3) - 2rem);
  margin: 1rem;
  height: 200px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 1s;
  background-color: rgb(220, 220, 220);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="boxes">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code is working. What is your question tho?

Comment: Which empty space are you talking about?? Everything seems to be fine

Comment: @flppv If you click the second box, it leaves only the first box in that top row and then empty space. Vikas solved it by having it stretch to fill, but ultimately I’d like a different box in the grid to fill that space.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```js
$(".box").click(function(){
    $('.box').removeClass("enlarge");
    $(this).toggleClass("enlarge");
});
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}

.enlarge {
    flex-basis: 100% !important;
}

.boxes {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
 .box {
        flex-basis: calc((100% / 3) - 2rem);
        flex-grow:1;
        display:flex;
        margin: 1rem;
        height: 200px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        text-align: center;
        transition: all 1s;
        background-color: rgb(220, 220, 220);
        align-items:center;
        justify-content:center;

    }
```

```html
<div class="boxes">
    <div class="box">1</div>
    <div class="box">2</div>
    <div class="box">3</div>
    <div class="box">4</div>
    <div class="box">5</div>
    <div class="box">6</div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: That works nicely, thanks!

Is it possible to not have the other boxes stretch to fill the space, but simply wrap? I'm guessing that would require reordering of elements?

For example, you click on box 2 and it pushes boxes 1 and 3 below it.